# send Enter(~) key using vba to an outside IE object

Tags: html, vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm stuck with the following task: from an excel file I send data (for a certain column into the sheet I send the cell values) to a specific IE object predefined.

The data is sent onto the website in a textarea field (identified onto the website through an ID:id1) using a macro. For each cell value/data added into the textarea field of the website Enter key/command need to be done/appended automatically as this will generate some of the empty input fields to be completed automatically onto the website (the code is listed below:)

I'm struggling with a method of automatically send the ENTER key onto the website into the textarea after the data is inserted

Code updated..

```
Sub adddata()

    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim objTR As Object
    Dim i, j, counter As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    counter = 1

    Set objIE = GetIeByTitle("https://exampletest.com", True, True)

    Dim lastRow2 As Integer
    lastRow2 = Workbooks(path1).Worksheets("Test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Workbooks(path1).Worksheets("Test").Activate

    contor = 1

    'First of all the unhidden files have to be take from the target excel file
    'Selecting the unhidden lines from the excel file
    For j = 1 To lastRow2
        If Rows(j).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            Workbooks(path1).Worksheets("Test").Range("A" & j & ":Z" & j).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test2").Range("A" & counter).PasteSpecial
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next j

    'look into the new excel file containing just the unhidden lines
    'Afterwards a look up through new excel file cells
    For i = 2 To counter
        objIE.document.getelementbyid("id1").Value = Worksheets("Test2").Range("C" & i).Value ' taking the value from the cell and adding it on the text area field
        objIE.document.getelementbyid("id1").SetFocus
        Application.SendKeys "~" ' sending the enter key
        Application.Wait (7)     ' add the delay of 7 seconds

        '2nd field
        objIE.document.getelementbyid("id2").Value = Worksheets("Test2").Range("D" & i).Value

        '3rd field
        objIE.document.getelementbyid("id3").Value = Worksheets("Test2").Range("E" & i).Value

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  It would not compile...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like youre missing a closing bracket here:

```
Set objIE = GetIeByTitle("https://exampletest.com", True, True ***)***
```

Try putting braces around the tilde:

```
    Application.SendKeys "{~}"
```

EDIT:

It sounds like perhaps there is code associated with the change of the text box; perhaps try:

```
objIE.document.getelementbyid("id1").fireevent ("onchange")
```

Comment: @georgian1990 Are you getting an error message? fixing the code in the OP so that it contains a compilable [mcve] would also help people help you. "is not working" simply isn't a constructive comment.